# AJAX Add a dynamic form and AJAX Post data

Tags: asp.net, ajax, forms

This is what I'm trying to do with AJAX:

[DropDownList]

I have a DropDownList (not inside an UpdatePanel), populated by different Products to "Add" to the database.

[UpdatePanel #1]

Below, I have an Conditional UpdatePanel that listens for "SelectedIndexChanged" on the DropDownList, when that event is triggered it adds TextBoxes to a div "productForm" inside the UpdatePanel. It creates the Form according to the Product to add.

[Button]

Below the UpdatePanel I have a button that "should" submit the form above.

[UpdatePanel #2]

I have an update panel that listens for the event on Button "Click" event. I also have a div in the ContentTemplate that should post out data that was submitted from the "Add Product Form" in the first UpdatePanel.

The thing is, when I submit (and the Controls are still visible in the first UpdatePanel. It can't read the data from the TextBoxes becaus they aren't there. Also, if I try to add all this to the same UpdatePanel, the Controls disappear whenever I click the Submit button.

Any ideas how to make something similar work?

Answer (score 0):

Without the code I can suspect that when you dynamically populate first div on dropdown selected index changed event, since its within update panel, viewstate is never made aware of new controls and on submit can't post them back to server.

I've had some bad experiences with update panel and never use it other than very simple scenarios. Try getting familiar with jQuery ajax. I would do what you want to do using jQuery and web methods.